# Failed loading xdebug.so undefined symbol: zend_empty_string

Tags: php, apache, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I can't debug PHP script in Visual Studio Code - Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS).

Before Update, the Xdebug version I was fettching error such as :

> Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320170718.
>   The Zend Engine API version 320160303 which is installed, is outdated.

After an update the Xdebug version now fetching following error:

> Error: Failed loading /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so:  /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_empty_string.

This is my PHP status:

```
php -v

PHP 7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Apr 18 2019 14:12:38) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.17-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

Please correct me if anything is missing at my end.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the tailored wizard from the Xdebug website:

[Xdebug Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

It seems that you are mixing the PHP versions: The Zend Engine API version **20160303** corresponds to PHP 7.1. For 7.2 you will need API version **20170718**.

I suppose you have several versions of PHP active - most probably 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3. In such case you need to run the proper phpize -  **phpize7.2** when going through the wizard.